# IndexError: list index out of range - PythonError

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, indexing, index-error

I'm creating a program that should create a file (.txt) based on each line of 'clouds.txt'. This is my code:

```
def CreateFile():
    global file_name
    f = open(file_name,"w+")
    f.write(list_email + ":")
    f.close()

def WriteInConfig():
    f = open("config/config.txt","a")
    f.write(list_name + "\n")
    f.close()



with open("clouds.txt","r") as f:
    
    list_lines = sum(1 for line in open('clouds.txt'))
    
    lines = f.readline()
    for line in lines:
            
        first_line = f.readline().strip()
        list_email = first_line.split('|')[1] #email
        print("Email: " + list_email)

        list_pass = first_line.split('|')[2] #pass
        print("Pass: " + list_pass)
            
        list_name = first_line.split('|')[3] #name
        print(list_name)

        global file_name
        file_name = "config/." + list_name + ".txt"

        with open('clouds.txt', 'r') as fin:
            data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
        with open('clouds.txt', 'w') as fout:
            fout.writelines(data[1:])

        CreateFile()
        WriteInConfig()
```

The clouds.txt file looks like this:

```
>|clouds.n1c0+mega01@gmail.com|cwSHklDIybllCD1OD4M|Mega01|15|39.91|FdUkLiW0ThDeDkSlqRThMQ| |x
|clouds.n1c0+mega02@gmail.com|tNFVlux4ALC|Mega02|50|49.05|lq1cTyp13Bh9-hc6cZp1RQ|xxx|x
|clouds.n1c0+mega03@gmail.com|7fe4196A4CUT3V|Mega03|50|49.94|BzW7NOGmfhQ01cy9dAdlmg|xxx|xxx >
```

Everything works fine until 'Mega48'. There I get "IndexError: list index out of range"

```
>|clouds.n1c0+mega47@gmail.com|bd61t9zxcuC1Yx|Mega47|50|10|Xjff6C8mzEqpa3VcaalUuA|xxx|x
|clouds.n1c0+mega48@gmail.com|kBdnyB6i0PUyUb|Mega48|50|0|R6YfuGP2hvE-uds0ylbQtQ|xxx|x
|clouds.n1c0+mega49@gmail.com|OcAdgpS4tmSLTO|Mega49|50|28.65|xxx|  >
```

I checked and there are no spaces/other characters. As you could see, after creating the file, the program deletes the line. After the error, if I'm starting the program again (and starts from 'Mega47') it doesn't show the error, and everything works as planned.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I hope by `[1]` you don't mean the 1st index, since, in Python indexing starts from 0

Comment: @MelvinAbraham no. I want the email and the second string after it. I'm very sure, it's 2nd and 3rd index ([1] and [2])

Comment: do you understand that every time you read a line there is one line less to be read? At the first try, your file has 4 lines and you read the first by doing lines = f.readline(). I think you should delete this and do for line in range(list_lines) instead

Comment: @FlavioMoraes now it's blocking at 'Mega99' list_email = first_line.split('|')[1] #email
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite - is it what you expected? If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

Comment: guys thanks for the help. I found the problem :D

Comment: you found or I did? XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see many mistakes in your code. First, what do you want with this `list_lines = sum(1 for line in open('clouds.txt'))`?
You have a problem in your for loop because you did `lines = f.readline()` so lines is the first line, then you do `for line in lines` where line will be each character of the first line and there are more character in the first line than lines in your file to read.

[edited]

you don't need to know the number of lines in the file to do a for loop. You can just do `for line in f:`, then you don't need to read the line again with `readline` it is already in the variable `line`

Comment: Well the program should read the first line only, then to delete the line. This action in loop till the end of clouds.txt.

Comment: list_lines = sum(1 for line in open('clouds.txt')) this is should show the total lines from clouds.txt.. but I forgot to print the value